# Laravel 5.4 Relationships Route Binding

Tags: laravel-5, routes, relationship

I am making an image gallery. Images have a many to many relationship with tags. Images also have a many to many relationship with catagories.

```
$images = $category->images;
$images = $tag->images;

public function images(Category $category = null)
{   
    $images = $category->images;

    return view('pages.images.index', compact('images'));
}
```

Route model binding on this code works fine and I can do the same for tags but what I am looking to do is filter on category and then tag.

```
$images = $tag->category->images;
```

For example, if I had an image with the tag of "dog" and a category "brown" the query would only return all dogs that are brown.

Can I do this? Both tags and categories could have multiple options so I was hoping for a route like this...

mysite.com/images/{category}/{tag}

Thanks for any help or best direction to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the build in laravel whereHas functionality

```
Image::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
    $query->where('NAME', '=', $category);
})->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) {
    $query->where('NAME', '=', $tag);
})->get();
```

replace the NAME with the desired field you want to filter on.

Comment: Thanks! This query works great.  I can pass in the "tag" with route binding mysite.com/images/{tag}  and then ?category=brown to pass in the filter.  Do you know a way I can pass that in with the route like this?  mysite.com/images/{tag}/{category}

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the route just as you stated and then use them as parameters in the controller-method which is connected to the route.

So if you declare a route like `Route::get('/register/{token1}/{token2}','RegisterController@confirm');`then it is possible to get those wildcards in the method confirm just like normal parameters:
`public function confirm(Request $request, $token1, $token2) {}`

Comment: Works great! Thought I had tried that with no success. Possibly interfering with the route binding or perhaps because I didn't have Request $request in the parameters. Anyway, thank you and @MrChrissss for the help! The combination of the two answers got me there.